# first child selector working but not last child selector in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to make a image slider. so i made two button to switch to next image. The problem is the image switch button is not going to its place. The css :first-child selector working but not the last child selector. I don't know why this is happening.

I try last-of-type and it start to work. but still i don't have a idea why last-child not working could anyone explain it to me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Image Slider</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      html {
        font-size: 62.5%;
      }

      body {
        background: url("http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg")
          no-repeat center center / cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        transition: 0.3s all linear;
        position: relative;
      }
      .btn {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 5rem;
        padding: 0 1rem;
        border: 0.1rem solid blue;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        color: #fff;
        outline: 0.3rem solid #0000ff4a;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        &:first-child {
          left: 0%;
        }
        &:last-child {
          right: 0%;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="btn"><</button>
    <button class="btn">></button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me here - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qBwWZBN but not in the snippet

Comment: The Snippet functionality here appends a `script` element and a `div.as-console-wrapper` to the body - so that the second button element simply _isn't_ the last child any more. With your actual issue, it is likely something similar. And by using your browser dev tools to inspect the DOM, you can easily verify such things ...

Comment: @CBroe When i use :nth-child(2) it's working but i don't have a idea how to solve this with inspect in DOM

Comment: @Paulie_D Not in browser either.

Comment: I didn't say inspecting the DOM would _solve_ the issue, I merely said that you can easily _detect_ what causes the issue here.

Comment: ok, instead of last-child "last-of-type" is working the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:first-of-type` and `last-of-type`. Also, use `&lt;` and `&gt;` HTML entities for the arrows to avoid misinterpretation by the browser.

Concerning `last-child`: There are often scripts inserted at the bottom of the `body` tag, which are not visible (except with the browser inspection tools), but one of which if "oficially" the last child inside `body`. So using `last-of-type` is safer here.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  background: url("http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg") no-repeat center center / cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: 0.3s all linear;
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 5rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border: 0.1rem solid blue;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0.3rem solid #0000ff4a;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.btn:first-of-type {
  left: 0;
}

.btn:last-of-type {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button class="btn">&lt;</button>
  <button class="btn">&gt;</button>
</body>
```

Comment: but i was targeting .btn class last child

Comment: Well, last-child doesn't refer to *classes*, but to *tags*, in this case that would be *any* tag which is a last child *and* has this class (but *not* the tag where this class appears for the last time). BTW, also `last-of-type` doesn't refer to classes, but to tags, but in this case that's the last appearance of the `button` tag which also happens to have the `.btn` class.